# Set gateway for specific ip destination and port

Tags: windows, networking, static-routes, netsh

I have two internet connections. One has a static public ip address (WAN-STATIC gateway ip 10.0.0.1) and the other has a dynamic public ip address (WAN-DYNAMIC gateway ip 10.0.0.254). I wish to force traffic to specific ip addresses and ports to use WAN-STATIC. I tried to do this with a dual wan router but after a long telephone call with the support team it seems this is not possible in the router. I tried this:

```
 route add xxx.xxx.xxx.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1 metric 1
```

This redirects my traffic correctly but i also need to specify the port. For example traffic to xxx.xxx.xxx.1 on port 80 needs to use the default gateway and traffic on port 8080 needs a static route. My computers runs on windows 7.

Comment: It sounds like you desire [policy based routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) which ideally is implemented in your router, although also native support exists in the current Linux kernel as well, but not in Windows as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've hinted in the question, you can statically route specific ranges/hosts via the operating system or router's routing tables.

Dynamically routing ports however, is not possible on Windows. Routing is a **Layer 3 task**, whereas ports are **Layer 5**. See the below diagram for more information:

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC197700.gif))</sub>

If you're determined, you can use a Linux router running the iptables firewall to re-route packets according to their port - you'll need separate routing tables to handle the specific ports, and then use `fwmark` to mark each packet. See [this forum post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/centos-static-route-to-nic-depending-port-4175466138/#post4972818) as a starting point.

Comment: So there is also no way to force email (port 25) to use a certain gateway.

Comment: @Nebu - not unless you want to spin up your own custom firewall/router and use iptables as I said in my closing paragraph.

Comment: Any closing arguments on how other companies solve this issue in a windows environment. I would be surprised if i am the only one facing this issue.

Comment: Essentially it's not possible - you're attempting to bridge two OSI layers, which is only possible with software, and unfortunately the software doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: Off topic, but that layer chart is bogus. E.g. how is "80" a layer? The [internet doesn't use the OSI layer model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#Abstraction_layers). (It's similar but there are no session or presentation layers.)

Comment: That... still has presentation and session layers? How about this one: http://www.w3.org/People/Frystyk/thesis/tcp.gif  Edit: Here's a better one: https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC197700.gif

Comment: Ports are not in layer-5, ports are layer-4 addresses, just like IP addresses are layer-3 addresses, and MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses. The RFCs make this clear. RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol says, "_To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP  communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of addresses or ports within each host._"