# How to send outgoing TCP packets on Windows through a remote Linux server?

Tags: windows, routing, proxy, packet, mitmproxy

Let's say I have a Windows computer and a Linux server. I'm looking for a way to route **outgoing** TCP packets on the Windows computer (all ports) through the Linux server.

The Linux server would have something like Ettercap to modify those packets before sending them out to the destination address.

I'm wondering if there is any way to accomplish the packet rerouting I described. Maybe there are proxy server programs or something? **The problem is it has to do it with any TCP packet, not just HTTP(S) traffic.**

The goal is to modify an address string (bolded below) in the packet data. Example:

> {"method": "login", "params": {"login":
>   "**143v3cYrnwVJss3VDBEam6iYdecmpXzT3t8VNu6hcSz3TKDyFYYfvnPzqfEpD1VYoaRya4B7oANGE2a2W8k2ahbT7qxq8L**",
>   "id": 1}

EDIT: I originally wanted to do this for a specific port but doing it for all traffic would also be fine if that is possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set gateway for specific ip destination and port](https://serverfault.com/questions/639380/set-gateway-for-specific-ip-destination-and-port)

Comment: It is unclear what packets you want to use that gateway for and what not. You say all TCP packets, but what about other protocols? The simplest might be to do it for all traffic to the intended destination IP and not just TCP. Also modifying protocol layer in flight on a packet by packet basis is difficult and in case of https close to impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it not possible. Same [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/639380/set-gateway-for-specific-ip-destination-and-port) was asked before. So easiest way to do it, to make additional gateway with Linux, where make your modifications.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a specific port and just send all traffic instead?

Comment: @Pacnet you looking for software, that could modify TCP packets?

Comment: Yeah I'm also looking for something that could do that. Right now I'm trying to use WinDivert and it seems to be going well, but if you know anything else, it would be helpful in case this doesn't work. Already exhausted Ettercap and scapy